# Custom charts.js with quadrants and lines x,y

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, html5-canvas, chart.js

How to configure the chart to look like the image below?
Can someone help me, I already researched a lot and found nothing

[image: Chart custom]

Comment: Kindly try to explain your question in more detail. Are the lines here values for some variable?

Comment: The position of the point is defined by the variables x and y. so far so good, my question is how can I leave the graphical charts.js like the one in the image, divided into four quadrants and the red line from the x and y axis to the meeting point.